# Is their any work done infinite Steiner quadruple systems?

Tags: combinatorial-designs

Is there any work done on infinite Steiner quadruple systems? I know of some work by Cameron and others on infinite Steiner triple systems.

Comment: Please see maass form.

Comment: Where should I look on Maass form. The link doesn't display anything obviously relevant.